# Reading text and assigning a class to data in Python

Tags: python, class, readfile

I've been searching around, and had no luck finding anything answering my question.

Essentially I have a file with the following data:

```
Title - 19
Artist - Adele 
Year released - 2008
1 - Daydreamer, 3:41, 1
2 - Best for Last, 4:19, 5
3 - Chasing Pavements, 3:31, 7
4 - Cold Shoulder, 3:12, 3

Title - El Camino 
Artist - The Black Keys 
Year released - 2011 
1 - Lonely Boy, 3:13, 1 
2 - Run Right Back, 3:17, 10 

EOF
```

I know how to create classes, and how to assign an object to a class and values to that object, but I am just about ready to tear my hair out on how it is I'm supposed to process the text. From text, I need to create a title for the album, and assign the album's information to it. There's more else besides that needs to be done, and there are more lines to be read, and I just don't know where to start on this. I've found two "album.py" files via google, and I've been unable to make heads or tails of how to apply the solution to my case.

And yes, this is for a school assignment. I've done some digging around and found some things relevant, but I'm just not understanding it. I'm new to programming in general, and I've made progress but this seems too far over my head.

I know I could reduce this to lists using split (\n\n) and operating on a series of progressively smaller lists, but I am trying to avoid this method at all costs.

EDIT:

For the time being, it's best to assume I know nothing. Though, to answer below question: I can open the file and read it. If its a consistent CSV formatted file, I can write code to process the enclosed data, and create a class structure that uses that data. Right now I'm just having trouble with the first three lines, and the digits immediately below.

APRIL 4 2012:

Okay, I have some code, I've left the comments with respect to it underneath.

```
def getInput():
    global albums
    raw = open("album.txt","r")
    infile = raw
    raw.close
    text=""
    line = infile.readline()
    while (line != "EOF\n" ):
        text += line
        line=infile.readline()
    text=text.rstrip("\n\n")
    albums=[str(n) for n in text.split("\n\n")]
    return albums


class Album():
    def __init__(self, title, artist, date):
        self.title=title
        self.artist=artist
        self.date=date
        self.track={}

    def addSong(self, TrackID, title, time, ranking):
        self.track+={self}

    def getAlbumLength(self):
        asdf=0
    def getRanking(self):
        asdf=0

def labels(x): #establishes labels per item to be used for Album Classifier
    title=""
    artist=""
    date=""

    for i in range(0,len(albums),1):
        sublist=[str(n) for n in albums[i].split("\n")]
        RANDUMB=len(albums[i])
        title=sublist[0]
        artist=sublist[1]
        date=sublist[2]

        for j in range(0,len(sublist),1):                
            song_info = [str(k) for k in sublist[3:].split("," and " - ")]
            TrackID=song_info[0]
            title=song_info[1]
            time=song_info[2]
            ranking=song_info[3]

getInput()
labels(albums)
```

Personal comments on code:
I was trying to avoid getting it into lists because I anticipated this problem. As the functions are concerned, I have to use every single bloody one, because it's in the assignment requirements... I am displeased because I could probably get around using them. The code is working sufficiently enough, except for the last part of it where I am trying to take the song information. I want to split the song information into lists, which are nested into the album information list. Something like:

```
[Album title, Artist, Date released,[01,Song,3:44,2],[02,Song,0:01,9]....]
```

The current code gives me index out of range error as of right now... I am using python3.

TLDR: The substance of my problem has thus changed from one of trying to solve how to go about starting the solution to how to take items in a list and convert them into nested lists.

Comment: Maybe you could post what you've got so far? Exactly what part are you having trouble with? Opening a file for reading? How to read lines from a file? How to create the album class? How to assign a value to a class variable?

Comment: Why are you afraid to split on lists?  '\n\n' is the *only* delimitter available that I can see so far. If you aren't splitting on two newlines, how are you going to demarcate the beginning of one object and the end of another?

Answer (score 0):

If you end up editing your question to contain some more specific examples of what is giving you trouble, I will edit this answer. But to address your general question, there are some steps involved to achieving your goal.

1. Like you said, you need to write a class that reflects the structure you intend to have from this data.
2. You will need to parse this file, probably line by line. So you have to determine if this file format is consistant. If it is, then you need to determine:

   1. What is the delimiter between each **set** of data, which will be conformed into a class instance?
   2. What is the delimiter between each field of each line?

When you are looping over each line, you will know that you need to start a new album object whenever you encounter a blank line.

When you know you are starting a new album, you can assume that the first line will be a title, the second an artist, the third, the year, etc.

For each of these lines you will also have to have rules of how to split each one into the data you want. At a basic level it can be a simple set of splits. At a more advanced level you might define regular expressions for each type of line.

Comment: @ jdi thank you, this is what i was looking for. I don't want to add too much information for the sake of the fact that I'm not making assumptions on what I know because I could be wrong.
My problem is exactly that I have no idea how to split the data. I assume it's by way of <var>.split("\n\n"). I assume I would just strip the leading text before the actual title/artist/year, but even this I don't know how to process. I'd offer my code 
I'd show you my code, but all I'm doing so far is reading the file, storing the data and closing the file.

Comment: @T_Poda: You shouldn't need to read the whole data in at once. Just loop over it line by line and change your "state" as you go. If you hit a blank line, you know you need to make a new one. If you end up posting any code, I will comment on it.